# pull specific data using scrapy in python (jupyter notebook)?

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

I am trying to run a spider using jupyter notebook to grab specific data - in this case, the result should grab "21 Servings" from the drop-down in the link.

I have the following code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class DCspider( scrapy.Spider ): 
    name = "dcspider"

    def start_requests( self ):
        urls = [ 'https://www.bodybuilding.com/store/alpha-lion/superhuman-pre-workout.html' ] 
        for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request( url = url, callback = self.parse )     
    def parse( self, response ):
        links = response.css('#skugroup-select > div > div.bb-dropdown > div.bb-dropdown__label.bb-dropdown__label--custom > bb-dropdown-label > div:nth-child(2) > div.sku-chooser__label-value').extract()
        filepath = '/path/as.csv'
        with open( '/path/as.csv', 'w' ) as f:
            f.writelines( [link + '/n' for link in links] )

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(DCspider)
process.start()
```

It runs fine but it doesn't grab anything so I am not sure if the mistake comes from the selector path or I am doing something else wrong? (When I tried any path had the same 0 outcome)

Here is part of the message after running the spider.

```
2019-12-31 13:03:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-12-31 13:03:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-12-31 13:03:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-31 13:03:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-12-31 13:03:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.bodybuilding.com/store/alpha-lion/superhuman-pre-workout.html> (referer: None)
2019-12-31 13:03:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I hope anyone can find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your selector:
it should be:

```py
links = response.css('div.bb-dropdown__label.bb-dropdown__label--custom > bb-dropdown-label > div > div.sku-chooser__label-value').extract()
```

because `#skugroup-select` does not contain desired thing.

With this selector I get:

```
<div class="sku-chooser__label-value">21 Servings</div>/n<div class="sku-chooser__label-value">Hulk Juice</div>/n%
```

in the file. and if you change `'/n'` to `'\n'` you will get what you are looking for:

```
<div class="sku-chooser__label-value">21 Servings</div>
<div class="sku-chooser__label-value">Hulk Juice</div>
```

I recommend printing links, and advancing the selector step by step for debugging.

Comment: I see that the spyder was correct, but the issue was the selector. I am trying to printing links but i got NameError: name 'response' is not defined.